# Processing Parameters Passed to defmacro in Common Lisp

Tags: lambda, macros, common-lisp

While trying to solve a problem in Project Euler, I wrote the following function and macro:

```
(defun digits (n &key (base 10)) ;; Returns a list with the digits of 'n'
   (if (< n base) (list n)       ;; in a given base.
      (multiple-value-bind (div rem)
         (floor n base)
         (concatenate 'list (digits div :base base) (list rem)))))

(defmacro test-palindromes (n1 n2)
   (let* ((dn1 (digits n1)) (dn2 (digits n2))
          (hash (loop for i in dn1 ; A-list describing digit associations
                      collecting (assoc i (pairlis dn2
                            (loop for i from 0 below (length dn1)
                                  collecting i))))))
      `(lambda (n1 n2) (and ,@(loop for i in hash
                                    for j from 0
                                    collecting `(char= (char n1 ,(cdr i)) (char n2 ,j)))))))
```

What I would like to do is generate a lambda which returns `T` if a string corresponds to a specific permutation of another string. For example:

```
1 > (pprint (macroexpand-1 '(test-palindromes 1089 9801)))

(LAMBDA (N1 N2)
  (AND (CHAR= (CHAR N1 3) (CHAR N2 0))
       (CHAR= (CHAR N1 2) (CHAR N2 1))
       (CHAR= (CHAR N1 1) (CHAR N2 2))
       (CHAR= (CHAR N1 0) (CHAR N2 3))))
1 >
```

It works fine when the inputs are integers...

```
1 > (funcall (test-palindromes 1089 9801) "ALAS" "SALA")
T
1 > (funcall (test-palindromes 1089 9801) "ALAS" "SALE")
Nil
```

... but flops if I try to give it more complex inputs:

```
1 > (setf g 10)
10
1 > (funcall (test-palindromes 1089 (+ 9791 g)) "ALAS" "SALA")
> Error: The value (+ 9791 G) is not of the expected type REAL.
> While executing: CCL::<-2, in process listener(1).
> Type :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> Type :? for other options.
2 >
```

In desperation, tried a clumsy solution by setting `dn1` and `dn2` to `(eval (digits dn1))` and `(eval (digits dn2))`. This yielded a partial improvement...

```
2 > (funcall (test-palindromes 1089 (+ 9791 g)) "ALAS" "SALA")
T
```

... but this code still flops:

```
(loop for pos from 0 to 66
      nconcing (loop for i in (nthcdr (1+ pos) 4-digits)
                     for j from 0
                     when (equal (sort (digits (nth pos 4-digits)) #'<)
                                 (sort (digits i) #'<))
                       collect (test-palindromes (nth pos 4-digits) i)))
> Error: Unbound variable: POS
> While executing: CCL::CHEAP-EVAL-IN-ENVIRONMENT, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Retry getting the value of POS.
> Type :? for other options.
3 >
```

(The variable `4-digits` contains an ordered list of all perfect squares with 4 digits.)

I guess something that should have gotten `eval`'ed was skipped, but I didn't really understand what happened in the loop. Why is `pos` no longer recognized? Can this loop made to work? Any input is appreciated.

Thanks,
 Paulo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in the body of `defmacro` is executed when the code is being interpreted or compiled at REPL or from a file. In the last loop of your `test-palindromes` you give the macro the argument `(nth pos 4-digits)` - but `pos` only has a sensible meaning when the `loop` is *being executed*.

So, what you try to do cannot be done with a macro, because the output of your macro depends on the values of the inputs *at execution time*.

But you can just use a function:

```
* (defun test-palindromes (n1 n2)
    (let* ((dn1 (digits (eval n1))) (dn2 (digits (eval n2)))
           (hash (loop for i in dn1
                       collecting (assoc i (pairlis dn2
                                                    (loop for i from 0 below (length dn1)
                                                          collecting i))))))
      (lambda (n1 n2)
        (loop for i in hash
              for j from 0
              always (char= (char n1 (cdr i)) (char n2 j))))))
TEST-PALINDROMES
* (test-palindromes 1089 9801)
#<COMPILED-LEXICAL-CLOSURE (:INTERNAL TEST-PALINDROMES) #x21012A08CF>
* (funcall * "ALAS" "SALA")
T
```

If you, for some reason, with to unroll the contents of the lambda in the manner you did in your macro (that is, instead of a `loop`, execute an `and` form containing `char=` comparisons), you can also do that with a function:

```
(defun test-palindromes (n1 n2)
  (let* ((dn1 (digits (eval n1))) (dn2 (digits (eval n2)))
         (hash (loop for i in dn1
                     collecting (assoc i (pairlis dn2
                                                  (loop for i from 0 below (length dn1)
                                                        collecting i))))))
    (eval `(lambda (n1 n2) 
             (and ,@(loop for i in hash
                          for j from 0
                          collecting `(char= (char n1 ,(cdr i)) (char n2 ,j))))))))
```

But probably there's no use for this approach.

Comment: Regular macros are expanded during compile time (in compiled code; interpreters can expand them at run time), not read time.

Answer (score 2):

Your macro will only work with literal numeric arguments since then the arguments will be numbers at compile time, but as you have noticed a macro does not know anything about what values the expressions will have and thus you need to treat the arguments as expressions that turn into values. You cannot do `digits` on an expression since it might be a variable or an expression like `(+ 3 4)` and the macro gets that as data.

A macro is just for syntax transformation. Imagine I will make this function:

```
(defun check-numbers (num1 num2)
  (let ((same (= num1 num2))
        (palinfrom (test-palindromes num1 num2)))
    ...))
```

What will happen is that Common Lisp can compile this function at creation and as a result it will expand all macros and that includes `test-palindromes` with the symbols `num1` and `num2` as arguments. The macro needs to expand to code that evenrually evaluates these two to get the numbers and then it can do `digits` on that result. It cannot happen at compile time. It's the same with this:

```
(cond ((test x) ...)
      (t ...))
```

`cond` is a macro that turns this into a `if`. The values it gets is the code as structure. `test` and `x` are most likely non existent at the time of this expansion so the macro can only use it to produce this:

```
(if (test x)
    ...
    ...)
```

As a rule of thumb you should not make anything a macro if it can be made a function.